# Pros and Cons of vehicle maintenance done with dealer vs private company

Tags: maintenance, oil-change, scheduled-maintenance

I have Lexus CT200H hybrid vehicle & the regular dealer recommended maintenances are performed with Lexus dealer. But they charge too much especially for major maintenance like 30K miles maintenance.

One of my friends have recommended a private company like firestone or jiffy lube to get the same maintenance done but for better pricing. But I would like to understand if there is any real difference in maintenance performed with dealer?

Appreciate if you can provide the best one out of Firestone & Jiffy lube who can take good care of vehicles with better knowledge/ratings.

Comment: I understand your dilemma, but this question is too open to opinion. I would suggest you look at the reputations of the companies in your area. A good independent mechanic is often cheaper than a dealer and just as good, *if* they understand your car. Keep in mind hybrids can be strange beasts.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the authorized dealer maintenance costs more I would still recommend you to stick to it.Private dealers would be able to provide you a bit cheaper service but it might cost you more over the long run.

Cons:

- Bit expensive

Pros:

- trained technician who are experts in servicing only Lexus
- company recommended spare parts,oil,fluids etc
- correct engine oil, fluid level
- does not void warranty
- peace of mind

The private repair shops may work on two Lexus one week and might not see another for a month or even more.But company dealership technicians are trained to work on only Lexus so they know your vehicle more and can repair it more correctly and precisely 
The only issue with the dealer service is that it is a bit expensive but you get total satisfaction and peace of mind is guaranteed.